# How do HEALPix FITS files of CMB maps translate into ndarrays? What are the coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, healpy

I'm using Healpy (the HEALPix tools developed in Python) to read and write full-sky CMB maps.

I am confused as to how the coordinates of pixels on a sky map translates into entries of a numpy ndarray. How does one HEALPix pixel in a FITS file translate into an ndarray entry?

For example, let's say I have a generated CMB map, Nside=64, lmax=64, using the default RING scheme. The total number of pixels is given by Npix=12*Nside**2. So, for my example, that is 49152 total number of pixels.

The FITS file I have is in the format 1 column by 48 rows. (The 1 column is all temperature values.) So, I transform this file into a n-dim numpy ndarray. The shape of this array gives (48,1024).

Question 1: Is this 2-d array a projection of all the map pixels on the sky into "matrix" form? I think it is. Using my example, 48*1024 = 49152, the total number of pixels.

Question 2: Where does the 1024 standard come from? What does this mean in terms of a HEALPix map and its coordinates? How does one 2-dim ndarray entry (pixel) relate to another (by angle, by HEALPix position, etc.)?

For another example, map Nside=1024. When I convert this into a 2-dimensional ndarray, I get the shape (12288, 1024).

EDIT: Why does this convention of 1024-element arrays exist? How does this correspond to the pixel coordinates on a map?

Comment: Take the function healpy.fitsfunc.write_map()
Why is the IDL_fits parameter set to "If True, reshapes columns in rows of 1024, otherwise all the data will go in one column. Default: True."
Why 1024 columns, and how does this correspond to the coordinates of a HEALPix full-sky map?

Comment: 1024 is just to read/write faster. No relation to the sky location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best source of information about the HEALPIX pixelization is the Healpix primer:

http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/intro.htm

A map is a 1-dimensional vector, each index is a pixel in the sky.
you can turn pixel number into coordinates in the sky using `hp.pix2ang`.

Shaping it in rows of 1024 is just a trick to make read/write to disk faster.

Comment: I understand. The 1024 number has no relation to sky location. 

So, I have a map in RING scheme. I want to use `hp.pix2ang` to calculate the vector coordinates of each pixel in this map. 

How does one do this? The parameters for `hp.pix2ang` are the nside parameter and the Healpix pixel number.

Comment: Look at the documentation online

Comment: I understand that function. The question is rather where do your "pixel indices" for the "ipix" input parameter come from? A map is a 1-dim vector. All maps have pixels with indices? How could that be?

Comment: pixel is the position in the array. so first element is pixel 0, second is pixel 1.